# Inverse operator of $I-A$

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, hilbert-spaces

Let $H$ be an Hilbert space, $A:H\to H$ be a bounded linear operator such that
$$
\|A^{n_0}\|< 1\qquad\text{for some}\quad\; n_0\in\mathbb{N}.
$$
I have to show that $I-A$ is invertible.

My idea is to consider 
$$
S:=\sum_{n=0}^\infty A^n,
$$
where $A^n$ is defined by induction as usual.

Then
$$
(I-A)S=\lim_{n\to\infty} I-A^{n+1}.
$$

We have just to show 
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty}A^{n+1}=0.
$$

Any ideas?

Comment: The spectral radius of $A$ is strictly upper bounded by $1$ and thus $1$ can't be an eigenvalue.

Comment: Presumably you have $\|A^n\| \le \|A\|^n$?

Comment: @copper.hat Yes, it's possible to show that!

Comment: Maybe I have to write $n$ in function of $n_0$ or something similar...

Comment: Show that $\sum_n A^n$ is convergent.

Comment: I think I need to show that $\sum_{n}\|A\|^n$ is convergent, but I can't

Comment: $\sum_{n} \left\|A\right\|^{n}$ *isn't* convergent in general, that's the whole point of this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Hint*:
\begin{align}
S = \sum_{m=0}^{\infty} \sum_{\ell = 0}^{n_{0} -1} A^{mn_{0}+\ell}
\end{align}

Comment: Is this a rearrangement of the series? Do we need to have the absolute convergence of the series to do this? Thanks!